# How to calculate next monthly day anniversary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a process I would like to run on a specific day of the month. What is the best way to calculate that anniversary each month? **For example, if I want to charge someone on the 30th of each month.**

I know there are GEMs I can install, but that seems like overkill. Also, the `Date#>>` method will only work for calculating the next month. What about the month after that?

*I've posted my code below that is the best solution I've come up.*

Comment: Consider using [Date#>>](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E).

Comment: @CarySwoveland the Date#>> method will only work for calculating the next month. What about the month after that?

Comment: If `d` is your `Date` object, `d >> 3` is the date on the same day-of-month `3` months hence (except sometimes when the `dom is > 28`). You can also step from one `Date` object to the next: `d = start_date; 12.times { <do something for value of `d`>; d = d >> 1 }`.

Comment: _"calculate that anniversary each month"_ – what do you mean by that? Do you want to run the method once a month or do you want the method to yield all upcoming dates? Furthermore, what is your input and your expected output before / on / after that date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your own answer, this would also work:

```
def next_month_anniversary(mday, today = Date.today)
  d = today.next_month
  if Date.valid_date?(d.year, d.month, mday)
    Date.new(d.year, d.month, mday)
  else
    Date.new(d.year, d.month, -1)
  end
end
```

or a little more condensed:

```
def next_month_anniversary(mday, today = Date.today)
  d = today.next_month
  mday = -1 unless Date.valid_date?(d.year, d.month, mday)
  Date.new(d.year, d.month, mday)
end
```

Example:

```
next_month_anniversary(30, Date.new(2018, 1, 31))
#=> #<Date: 2018-02-28 ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use advance

https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/advance

```
Date.current.advance(months: 2)
```

**Edit per comment:** Call advance on your initial date know any future occurrence

```
 my_date = Date.new(2018, 1, 30) #example but mean to be the date you set up as to be recurrent
 my_date.advance(months:1) #Wed, 28 Feb 2018
```

Comment: The OP wants to set the day of the month explicitly, for example to `30`.

Comment: He said "for example". To calculate next month and future ones w/o hard coding 1, advance is the most direct/easiest way to do it.

Comment: Sure, but your answer doesn't address the _"on a specific day of the month"_ part.

Comment: Regarding your edit: what if the initial date is `Date.new(2018, 2, 28)` – how could you advance it to March 30?

Comment: Why? Why would run a month in the 28th and the next on the 30th? You miss the point of a recurrent schedule. How would you get the date x day n months ahead using your method? Looping through your method? With advance all is done in one line call

Comment: Actually I found this one is a better answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have been able to come up with. In this scenario, It is Jan 31 and I would like to return an anniversary on the 30th of each month.

```
> MyClass.next_month_anniversary(30, '2018-01-30'.to_date)
 => Wed, 28 Feb 2018
```

Here is the code:

```
  def next_month_anniversary(day_of_month, today = Date.today)
    month = (today >> 1).month
    year =  (today >> 1).year
    days_in_month = Time.days_in_month(month.to_i, year.to_i)
    if days_in_month < day_of_month
      day = days_in_month
    else
      day = day_of_month
    end
    Date.new(year.to_i, month.to_i, day.to_i)
  end
```

Comment: _"It is Jan 31"_ – off by one, you are passing `'2018-01-30'`